# IIS 7.5 powershell module usage issues

Tags: powershell, module, iis-7.5

Has anyone managed to use this module with success, i'm running 32bit Windows 7, where i have opened an administrator shell using run as administrator, i have imported the WebAdministration module and then attempted to use the commands with some issues, have provided two examples here

**Websites**

I created a web site with the following command

```
new-website -name testsite -port 80 -hostheader testsite -physicalpath c:\temp
```

Then i attempted to get the sites details using the command
get-website -name testsite
but it always returns all sites, seems to ignore the -name parameter. Only way i can get the site is using a filter

```
get-website | ? { $_.name -eq 'testsite' } | get-member
```

When i use appcmd it works as expected using the following command

```
C:\> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list site testsite
```

**AppPools**

When i try to list the apppools using the following command

```
dir iis:\apppools
```

i get the following error

```
Get-ChildItem : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

Yet when i use appcmd as follows i get all the apppools as expected without any error

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list apppool
```

Has anyone successfully managed to use the WebAdministration module ?

Thanks in advance
Pat

Answer (score 9):

If you are already running PowerShell as an administrator and have Windows UAC disabled and you are still seeing this error, make sure WAS (Windows Process Activation Service) is running.  You can stop W3SVC but PowerShell will definitely give the same head-scratching "access denied" error if WAS is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the PowerShell window is running elevated, try right-clicking in the Start Menu and using the "Run as administrator" option to ensure it runs elevated.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Get-Website ignoring the -Name parameter, this appears to be a bug according to [this forum post](http://forums.iis.net/p/1167298/1943273.aspx).  The workaround is to use Get-Item

```
$website = "Default Web Site"
Get-Item "IIS:\sites\$website"
```

Be sure to use double quotes, variables are not expanded when single quotes are used.

Regarding browsing the application pools I suspect this is a permissions issue as CarlosAg mentioned. Make sure that you are running PowerShell with elevated privileges. I typically launch PowerShell by right-clicking on it and selecting "Run as administrator".